# Distinct values in List Agg function

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

[image: My Data in the tables]

[image: Simplification]

Now I want records for Name in Table A  which have different Values in Table B.

For example

```
* A will have records A1,A1,C1,D1
* B will have records B1,B1,B1,B1
* C will have records C1,C1
* D will have records D1,E1
* E will have only one record E1
```

I need output like

```
A A1,A1,C1,D1
D D1,E1
```

I used `ListAgg` function but it is giving me all records.

Can anyone please tell me how to get the records

Comment: Please see the attached pictures for more details

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Please type out your schema and sql

Comment: Please edit your question and show your SQL.

Comment: Are you sure that is your desired/needed output? It doesn't make much sense to me. As Gordon observed, you seem to want to leave out the "names" that have a single "value", whether that "value" appears just once or repeatedly, and to include only the "names" that have at least two distinct "values". I can't imagine what business problem may lead to such a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . You don't want to get unique values for `listagg()`.  You just want to filter out resulting rows where all the values are the same:

```
select a.name, listagg(b.value, ',') within group (order by a.id2) as val_str
from a join
     b
     on a.id2 = b.id2
group by a.name
having min(b.value) <> max(b.value);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use joins to join both the tables on id2 field.
then you can use select query with group by clause on 'Name' A table and group_concat(in oracle it is list agg) function to select concatenated string of value from B table.
.... if you are using mysql queries.